# How to change mysql_num_rows etc functions to mysqli?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

I am facing an error as I'm about to launch my `PHP` files to a free web hosting site. The error showing up is given below:

[image]

And below is the code for my project.

```
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE staff_id='$staff_id' AND password='$password'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());  //this is error on line 42
    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

I'm not sure what the errors are as I am self-taught on PHP. hopefully you guys can point out what change i should make. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your text editor and Replace ALL **mysql** with **mysqli**

Comment: Your mysql_query also requires the database connection along with the sql query. So, mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sqlCode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as you suggest in the title, use mysqli for security reasons, or even better, PDO.

With mysqli: **(updated)**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE staff_id = :staff_id AND password = :password");
$res = $stmt->execute(["staff_id" => $staff_id, "password" => $password);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

With PDO:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE staff_id = :staff_id AND password = :password");
$res = $stmt->execute(["staff_id" => $staff_id, "password" => $password);
$row = $res->fetchColumn();
```

`$conn` being your database link. The PDO version assumes you don't need the rows but just the count. In case someone tells you to, don't use `rowCount` on `SELECT` query, that's not reliable.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! very clear and simple to understand. thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be using prepared statements with mysqli as well; just throwing an `i` at the end does not make that more secure.

Comment: @deceze definitly you're right, updated the answer.

Comment: Great! Except mysqli's prepare doesn't work that way: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @deceze you can't put parameters in execute with mysqli ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE staff_id='$staff_id' AND password='$password'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());  //this is error on line 42
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

try this one

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE staff_id='$staff_id' AND password='$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con)); // $con is the connection to database like  // $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Hi @ParvejAlam, could you please give more explanation to your answer?

Comment: thanks!! i understand the logic behind this code!

Comment: i really appreciate if you understood. but as per my opinion the syntex have been changed in new php version. :)